# Leaflet markercluster draggable

Tags: draggable, leaflet, markerclusterer

I'm trying to do a draggable marker cluster but unsuccessfully. I hace seen many examples to do it with simple markers but not with clusters. I have seen there are some events to catch for cluster group but I think it´s not possible.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

Does anybody have tried to do it?

Thanks

Comment: That's not possible, at least the functionality isn't in L.MarkerCluster. It would require a fair amount of logic and there are (almost, that's you) no use cases for something like this.

Comment: Thanks @iH8 I will try to implement other easier solution